# Python - for-loop does not enter correct argument for boolean parameter

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement, boolean

I am trying to generate a for-loop in Python that should classify any number as prime/not prime. The suggested command is:

```
def prime_checker(number):
  is_prime = True
  for n in range(2, number):
    if number % n == 0:
      is_prime = False
  if is_prime == True:
    print("It is a prime number.")
  else:
    print("It is not a prime number.")
```

The suggested command above works well. However, I would like to generate the parameter as `is_prime = bool()` (i.e. with no standard value), and only after that the function will classify `is_prime` as either "True" or "False". The reason is that I do not like the idea of generating variables with standard arguments; instead I prefer to first generate variables populated with missing values, and only then to have them filled in with the proper argument. I tried this command, but it will output only "It is a prime number.":

```
def prime_checker(number):
  is_prime = bool()
  for n in range(2, number):
    if number % n == 0:
      is_prime = False
    else:
      is_prime = True
  if is_prime == True:
    print("It is a prime number.")
  else:
    print("It is not a prime number.")
```

I wonder if anybody knows why the command above will output only "It is a prime number."

Comment: You seem to think that `is_prime = bool()` is semantically different from either `True` or `False`, some sort of "undefined" boolean state. It is not; it's just an expensive way of defining `is_prime = False`. There is no missing value (although there is a *default* value for `bool`'s single parameter).

Comment: If you assign *bool()* to is_prime then you're implicitly setting it to False. None would be a better choice if you need to know if neither True nor False was ever assigned to it. Also, your loop is flawed. What if the value passed to your function is 2?

Comment: Many algorithms will start with the *assumption* that the result will be true or false, then look for a counterexample to reverse that assumption. (Here, you can assume a number if prime until you determine it is not, say by being less than 2 or having an even divisor of 3 or greater.)

Comment: Not being divisible by a single `n` doesn't make `number` prime, so setting `is_prime = True` when `number % n != 0` is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, indeed assigning `is_prime = bool()` make it "False", by default! I think the solution suggested by Lancelot du Lac and Robinood (making `is_prime = None`) satisfies my requirements. Regarding the loop problem in the initial solution, I see that it suffers from 2 issues: 1) Number "2" would have assigned `is_prime = False` (which is not true) because the default argument for "is_prime" is `bool()`, and because that number does not fall in the loop;

Comment: 2) as a matter of fact, the else-condition within the loop sets `is_prime = True` when `number` is not divisible by a single `n`, and that is the core of the issue in the initial solution. To be logically consistent, if `is_prime = True`, then `number` should not be divisible by any `n` within the range. Take for example `number=9`: the loop would set `is_prime = True` for the very first iteration just because "9" is not divisible by "2", but "9" is divisible by "3". I fixed that in my last solution published in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't like this idea, it is pretty standard in python (and in programmation in general) and often used. Anyway, the closest thing you could write would be:

```
is_prime = None
```

which is the equivelent in python to declaring a variable without assigning a value.

Comment: The reason I don't like this idea is because I am used to work with datasets. When generating new variables, it is advisable to start with missing values, not default values. Thank you for your suggestion which I added to my final command!

Answer (score 0):

It's because your second function does

```
else:
    is_prime = True
```

within the for-loop.
So if it discovers that it's not a prime number for one value of `n`, the next iteration(`n+1`) might make it so `is_prime` equal to `True`.

For example, if you're testing the number 4:

1. It's divisible by 2, so set `is_prime` to `False`
2. It's not divisible by 3, so set `is_prime` to `True`

You need to add a `break` after you discover it's not prime, so that it won't try and keep checking other numbers.

And doing `is_prime = bool()` sets it to `False`, anyway.

Finally, just an add-on, there are faster ways to check for primality:

```
import math
def is_prime(number):
  if number <= 2:
    print(number, "is prime!")
    return True
  for i in range(3, math.floor(math.sqrt(number))+1, 2):
    if number%i == 0:
      print(number, "is prime!")
      return True
  print(number, "is not prime!")
  return False
```

Answer (score 0):

My final command would be:

```
def prime_checker(number):
  is_prime = None
  if number <2:
    is_prime = False
    print(f"{number} is not prime")
  else:
    for n in range(2,number):
      if number % n == 0:
        is_prime = False
    if is_prime == False:
      print(f"{number} is not prime")
    else:
      is_prime = True
      print(f"{number} is prime")
```

Thank you for all who commented in this post! Any other comments are of course welcome.